# Count record with condition other table and multiple table

Tags: sql

---

need help from expert here....I need to count record where condition specific **customerID**  based on **hm_value**

Here is my table named risk

```
logNo    customerID 
r1        001
r2        002
r3        001
r4        001
```

Table named riskMov where the relation of **risk.logNo** and **riskMov.logNo** is **1:M**
Need to take one record from multiple id where latest date

```
logNo   hm_value  date_created
r1      11        2021-01-21
r1      12        2021-03-03
r2      14        2021-02-21
r3      13        2021-02-22
r3      12        2021-04-22
r4      13        2021-01-21
```

Customer table where the relation  **customer.customerID** and **risk.CustomerID** **1:M**

```
customerID   custName  
001          Oppo
002          Samsung
003          Nokia   
004          Motorola   
005          Huawei
```

HeatMap Table where the relation  **Heatmap.value** and  **RiskMov.hm_value** **m:1**

```
xAxis   yAxis   value
1         1       11
2         1       12
3         1       13 
4         1       14
5         1       15
```

I need return all count from table risk record where specific customerID condition .

I try use case when user customerId = '001' then null with multiple join of table but not expected result

Here is my attempt query

```
SELECT d."yaxis" AS y,
       d."xaxis" AS x,
       CASE
         WHEN c."customerid" = '001' THEN ( Count(DISTINCT a.customerid) )
         ELSE 0
       END       AS count
FROM   PUBLIC."risk" a
       INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT logno,
                                   hm_value
                   FROM   PUBLIC."riskmov") b
               ON a.logno = b.logno
       RIGHT JOIN PUBLIC."customer" c
               ON c.customerid = b."customerid"
       RIGHT JOIN PUBLIC."heatmap" d
               ON b."value" = d."value"
GROUP  BY d."yaxis",
          d."axis",
          c."cu_customer_id"
ORDER  BY d."yaxis",
          d."xaxis" DESC
```

My expected result as below

```
xAxis   yAxis   count(count record by specfic customer. eg- customerID = '001')
1         1       1
2         1       1
3         1       1 
4         1       0
5         1       0
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result is great, but can't you also show us your current query attempt?

Comment: Hi @jarlh sorry i forgot to put....I already edit my question...can refer above